# Help identifying this frame?

Tags: road-bike, vintage

I was told this was a Cinelli frame although it's clearly not. The fork seems to be original but I'm not sure of what it could be just by looking at its dropouts and lugs. The seat post is 26.8, english threaded and there is a "suntour pro" stamp on the dropouts.
I would seriously be glad if anyone could help!

[frame, dropouts, windowed lugs and fork crown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgFkM.jpg)

[serial number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCB0c.jpg)

oh! sorry for the weird rendering on the photos, my iphone has become senile.

Comment: Unfortunately, with a track bike there are fewer age-identifying features.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't look like a track frame to me. There are cable guides on the top tube, and the rear dropouts are horizontal, forward facing, with a derailer hanger.

Comment: Or did you mean the derailers, brakes, and other bits that would help to date the bike that are missing when a bike is setup like a trade bike?

Comment: haha not a track bike at all, i just used those single speed components because that's what i had on hand.
I only had access to the frameset, no idea on what other components came originally with this one.
someone pointed towards japanese frame at bikeforums.net, does anyone have a clue?

Comment: OK, if we just have a random frame with no components, one can observe that it's lugged, so not likely to have been produced in the past 5-10 years when welding became the norm.  And there are no lugs for downtube shifters, meaning it was either set up for stem shifters (prior to roughly 1985) or some sort of handlebar shifter (roughly after 1995).  The water bottle bosses on the downtube are placed high, suggesting an older bike, before oversized water bottles became the vogue.

Comment: Can't clearly all the cable lugs, but they appear to be the simple style designed for sheathed cables -- usually associated with cheaper bikes, and after maybe 1980.  One odd thing is that clamp on the seat tube.  It sort of looks like a downtube shifter mount, but normally there would be some sort of "stop" on the downtube (other than the  bottle boss) to keep the clamp from slipping, and I cannot see such a thing (but the pictures are poor quality).

Comment: The clamp on the seat-tube looks like a pump peg to me!

Comment: it is a clamp for a upperend suntour derailleur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the puzzle. It's a Caloi Triathlon. Although Caloi is a brazillian brand, they ordered 200 bikes from Suntour in 1985 for their racing teams. It came originalli with suntour shifting group, sugino cranks and nitto handlebars. It's such a rare ride over here, it's a shame the paint is no longer original and i have no access to a full range of the components, I really like to looks and weight of the frame.

[It was only made in this nice blue color.](http://mlb-s2-p.mlstatic.com/caloi-10-triathlon-1985-excelente-estadoleia-o-anuncio-10-475401-MLB20332084459_062015-F.jpg)

[A better look at the lugs on the top tube](http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/9229/fotosnicolasoubruna003.jpg)

Thanks for the chase, folks!

Comment: Another source who might be able to provide some background/back story is the guy who runs Yellow Jersey. Drop him a line, send some pictures, see what he thinks: http://www.yellowjersey.org

Answer (score 1):

The photo quality could be better, but it looks to me like it is a mid-range Japanese-made frame from the mid- to late-1980s. The rear dropouts are not stamped, so it's not a low-end frame, and the single shifter boss on the downtube is for unitized Shimano or Suntour shifters, like you can see on the bikes photographed in [this thread](http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/540967-finally-picked-em-up-1986-miyata-710-310-a.html).

It's hard to tell for certain just from what I see in the photos, but the lugs appeared to be thinned toward the ends, which is again not something you see on low-end frames.

If you ask this question in the [Classic & Vintage sub-forum](http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/) from which I linked the above thread, you'll likely get a quick and accurate answer. I wish I could tell you more, but I don't recognize the semi-wrapped seat stay lugwork, though I'd wager someone at BikeForums will know much more.

Comment: Yeah, the folks in C&V are awesome.

Comment: Ah!  What appeared to be a second water bottle boss was simply the shadow of the first boss on the wall.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, people! I actually opened this thread in the meantime of opening it also at bike forums, [please, take a look](http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/1020521-could-you-help-me-identifying-frame.html#post18012883)!

Answer (score 0):

I think I used to own the same frame. It's (if it's similar to my frame) a Mitsubishi Shogun type frame, although most pictures are not showing with the lugs and same head-tube. Please bear in mind that frames vary between years, not just models.

This is not my bike, but it's the same frame: https://rideblog.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/shogunrestore06.jpg?w=640&h=480

Hope this helps. Not saying it's this frame, but it looks very similar.

Comment: I can right away notice a bunch of differences -- more different than similar, I'd say.

Comment: Fair enough, just simply my opinion :3 I have always liked to ride lugged frames, as to why the Colnago road bikes seem so nice. I thought that this shogun was quite similar, but perhaps not! heheheh Thanks for the comment!

Comment: do you know the serial number pattern for this frame of yours? mine is two letters (S and I) plus six digits.

Comment: I physically can't get to it. Heheheh, It's covered by the cable guide on the bottom bracket shell, and is completely caked over with all sorts of gunk. I haven't used the bike in years, it's just sat at the back of my shed, doing pretty much nothing. I shall try to see if I can find the serial number later on when I get back, currently at work eheehheh. I think it's something similar to the pattern you've posted, but I am not promising anything! Hehehehe.

Comment: thanks for answering, mate, but i can spot several differences right away. take a look at the semi wrap seat cluster for instance